# How does Kotlinx.Serialization use encodeToJsonElement() function to serialize Any type?

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I'm trying to serialize an object into json format using `encodeToJsonElement`.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.ContextualSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.ExperimentalSerializationApi
import kotlinx.serialization.InternalSerializationApi
import kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.SerialDescriptor
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Encoder
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlinx.serialization.json.encodeToJsonElement
import kotlinx.serialization.modules.SerializersModule
import kotlinx.serialization.serializer

@Serializable
data class Person(
  val name: String
)

@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
private val json = Json {
  SerializersModule {
    contextual(Any::class, DynamicLookupSerializer)
  }
}

fun main() {
  f(Person("jack"))
}

fun f(data: Any) {
  val d = json.encodeToJsonElement(data)
}

@ExperimentalSerializationApi
object DynamicLookupSerializer : KSerializer<Any> {
  override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor =
    ContextualSerializer(Any::class, null, emptyArray()).descriptor

  @OptIn(InternalSerializationApi::class)
  override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Any) {
    val actualSerializer =
      encoder.serializersModule.getContextual(value::class) ?: value::class.serializer()
    encoder.encodeSerializableValue(actualSerializer as KSerializer<Any>, value)
  }

  override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Any {
    error("Unsupported")
  }
}
```

but this doesn't work.

```
Exception in thread "main" kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'Any' is not found.
Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied.
```